# 'WARNING: Tried to load angular more than once.' Karma warning

Tags: angularjs, gruntjs, karma-runner

I'm trying to set up Karma with a new project and I'm getting the following error

```
'WARNING: Tried to load angular more than once.'
```

My karma.conf.js looks like this

```
module.exports = function(config) {
  config.set({

    // base path that will be used to resolve all patterns (eg. files, exclude)
    basePath: '',


    // frameworks to use
    // available frameworks: https://npmjs.org/browse/keyword/karma-adapter
    frameworks: ['jasmine'],


    // list of files / patterns to load in the browser
    files: [
      'app/bower_components/angular/angular.js',
      'app/bower_components/angular-mocks/angular-mocks.js',
      'dist/js/combined.bower.js',
      'app/js/routes.js',
      'app/test/ENV.js',
      'app/js/**/*.js',
      'app/test/**/*.js'
    ],


    // list of files to exclude
    exclude: [
      'app/js/filter.list.js'
    ],


    // preprocess matching files before serving them to the browser
    // available preprocessors: https://npmjs.org/browse/keyword/karma-preprocessor
    preprocessors: {
      'app/js/**/*.js': ['env']
    },

    envPreprocessor: [
      'ENV'
    ],


    // test results reporter to use
    // possible values: 'dots', 'progress'
    // available reporters: https://npmjs.org/browse/keyword/karma-reporter
    reporters: ['progress'],


    // web server port
    port: 9876,


    // enable / disable colors in the output (reporters and logs)
    colors: true,


    // level of logging
    // possible values: config.LOG_DISABLE || config.LOG_ERROR || config.LOG_WARN || config.LOG_INFO || config.LOG_DEBUG
    logLevel: config.LOG_INFO,


    // enable / disable watching file and executing tests whenever any file changes
    autoWatch: true,


    // start these browsers
    // available browser launchers: https://npmjs.org/browse/keyword/karma-launcher
    browsers: ['PhantomJS'],


    // Continuous Integration mode
    // if true, Karma captures browsers, runs the tests and exits
    singleRun: false,

    // Concurrency level
    // how many browser should be started simultaneous
    concurrency: Infinity
  })
}
```

In order, I load Angular, angular-mocks, my combined bower assets in my dist folder, my routes, where my angular module definition is (not my idea), my an enviroment variable I need, my javascript controllers I want to test, my test folder. If I don't include my combined bower file, I get an error about not being able to load jquery, and then another for each of my other dependencies.

What can I do to fix this?

---

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `combined.bower.js` includes `angular` and `angular-mocks` bower packages (as file name says), these lines

```
  'app/bower_components/angular/angular.js',
  'app/bower_components/angular-mocks/angular-mocks.js',
```

should be omitted.